# Is my bard college of dance homebrew balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, bard, archetype

### College of Dance V.1

People of this college have learned to dance in such a way that it can control life and death. Dance has existed since before written literature. You have found a way to harness the ancient dances to control the battlefield.

#### Moves of the Dance

When you take this College at level 3, you gain the power of dance. You gain an extra 5ft of walking speed, to a maximum of 40. Whenever you take the dash action, you do not provoke opportunity attacks. And you have advantage on dexterity saving throws against traps.

#### Dance of Fate

Also when you take this college, you gain the power to grasp life and death within your dance. Once per long rest, you can start the dance of fate. During the dance, when you are within 10ft of a creature, you can expend a bardic inspiration die as a bonus action to do one of the following things.

- Make the creature lose movement equal to 5xProficiency bonus for a number of rounds equal to the the number rolled on the bardic inspiration die.
- Make the creature take necrotic damage equal to twice the roll on the bardic inspiration die.
- Heal the creature an amount of hp equal to twice the roll on the bardic inspiration die.

This dance lasts for 1 minute, you can do it twice per long rest at level 6, and 3 times per long rest at level 14.

#### Mantle of Dances

At 6th level, your dances have become more powerful. As a reaction to a creature starting its turn within 5ft of you during your Dance of Fate, you can attempt to charm them. The creature must make Wisdom save or be Charmed by you for the round. The creature cannot benefit from advantage on the saving throw.

You can do this a number of times equal to your charisma modifier (minimum of once).
This has no effect on constructs

#### Primal Dance

Beginning at 14th level, your power of dancing comes into full effect. Once per long rest, you can start a primal dance which lasts for 1 minute. During the dance, your speed becomes 5ft, you must spend your action trying to continue the dance. Whenever a hostile creature makes an attack roll while within 10 ft of you, they must make a  Charisma saving throw, or be Petrified for 4 rounds, If the creature succeeds, the have disadvantage on their next attack roll.

Once a creature has been affected by this feature, or if they succeed, they cannot be affected by this for 48 hours.
This feature ends early if you die.

Any feedback is welcome, but really, I would prefer feedback about what I should switch the abilities to if they are broken.

Comment: See [this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/62294) for some ideas about details you can include to improve your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Overall balance level seems underpowered until Primal Dance.

Most bard colleges grant more powerful abilities than this one.  Permanent summon, Extra Attack, basically automatic success on most social checks, being able to cherry pick overpowered spells from any list, these are bard college abilities available at these levels.  Weaponizing the bonus action is nice, but Whispers isn't considered a top tier or even good college and it grants more damage.

Like many things which utilize bonus action, it will be better if the character is  relatively underpowered to begin with and has no use for the bonus action.  If they are reliably picking up downed allies with Healing Word or Polearm Master attacking people already, it's much less good.

### Primal Dance is a save or die.

Gaining resistance to damage doesn't help you if people get to wail on you for four rounds, or all your allies die before you wake up.  Petrified for four rounds is a death sentence and Charisma is a *very* weak save for the majority of monsters.  Unless they somehow identify what the bard is doing (which is likely just metagaming on the DM's part) and just *avoid* him, they will get petrified, and then get murdered.  This ability is incredibly powerful and should largely neuter encounters on its own.  Now, it *is* a 14th level ability *and* it eats your whole turn every turn to keep it up.  But it is too powerful as written.  By a lot.

### I don't understand the theme of this college.

Dances which control life and death, but there's also fate mentioned, and turning people to stone?  Whatever this is referencing in terms of mythology or what have you, i'm not getting it.  It feels like a grab bag of vague abilities and the names don't really help put it into a context.  Things don't *need* a coherent theme or style to tie together mechanics ('grab bag of random abilities' describes most of 5e), but it does help.